# generate all possibilities from two fixed rows of entries?

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, formula

I spent hours trying to look for a solution and I feel like I got close but  figured asking would be the best way.

Lets say I have a table with 2 columns, column A is an item, and column B is a price for the item. This table has 12 entries. What I would like to do is generate additional tables of 6 entries that do not exceed a certain price. see below for example. The number i want these table to not exceed is 50,000.

for example the first entry could be an apple at 9,000 value. the apple is column a, and value column b.

Can someone help with a way to generate all combinations of 6 items from column a, that do not exceed a combined price of 50,000 in column b?

Comment: If you came pretty close it's definately worth showing your code/formula since it may just need some little tweaks. See [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your quesiton accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With 12 items you have 2<sup>12</sup>-1 or 4095 possible combinations of products.  These can map into the 12 bits of a 12-bit binary number. It is not difficult to write a macro to calculate the total cost of each combination and then filter the result to display results less than or equal to 50,000.

**EDIT#1:**

Please see:

[Best possible combination sum of predefined numbers that smaller or equal NN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764575/best-possible-combination-sum-of-predefined-numbers-that-smaller-or-equal-nn)

[Listing all possible combination without repetition,VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150054/listing-all-possible-combination-without-repetition-vba)

Comment: So i don't truthfully know how to write a macro. any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Calebs  See my **EDIT#1**